# How to generalize the kibana visualization (bar chart)

Tags: kibana-5

In Kibana visualization (bar chart), i have created the bar chart for one of the index pattern (eg: Aircel), I have created the another index pattern (eg: Nationwide), having the similar columns for both index patterns with different data.

My Question is how can create a common visualization of Bar char (called as bar chart template) so that it can be used for both Aircel and Nationwide indexes.

can you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use one visualization for two indexes. You can save them as same index, but two different types and then create visualization for both types on same bar chart. If you do not want to do this, you can create a dashboard and add both bar charts from different indexes there, so you will have them on the same page, but not on the same visualization

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can actually accommodate data from multiple indices inside the same Kibana visualization.

1. Create an index that represents multiple indices having similar fields or the indices you want to compare by naming "*" or anything like that.
2. Create the Y axis using "counts" aggregation or "sum" of "total" or whatever aggregation used in your data.
3. Create the X axis first using "Terms" aggregation using your data specified fields. Then add a sub-bucket "Split Series" upon that using "Terms" aggregation with the Field as "_index" or "_type" according to your data.